# Image getting currupt when uploading by ftp in php

Tags: php, ftp, upload

I am working on a self taught local project and trying to upload a file to a server.

but when I upload the image file it gets corrupted.

this is my upload.php

```
<?php
$ds          = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;  //1

$storeFolder = 'uploads';   //2

if (!empty($_FILES)) {

$tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];          //3             

$targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  //4

$targetFile =  $targetPath. $_FILES['file']['name'];  //5

move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile); //6


$ftp_server="myServer";
$ftp_user_name="userName";
$ftp_user_pass="Password";


$file = $targetFile;//tobe uploaded
$remote_file = $_FILES['file']['name'];

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// upload a file
if (ftp_put($conn_id, $remote_file, $file, FTP_ASCII)) {
echo "successfully uploaded $file\n";
exit;
} else {
echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
exit;
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);


}
?>
```

It currently uploads to the local folder `Uploads` also to the server but corruptted any help on this will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using FTP Binary? an image is a binary file not an ASCII file.

Comment: Please do not answer duplicate questions. Vote them to be closed as duplicate instead.